# How do I fetch all child/nested states of a given state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to add a bit of automation to the navigation in my SPA.

Essentially I have a couple of top-level states, with child/nested states beneath them.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', { url: '/' })
          .state('products', { url: '/products' })
          .state('products.details', { url: '/products/{productId}' })
          .state('products.details.images', { url: '/images' })
          .state('products.details.vendors', { url: '/vendors' })
          .state('products.details.attachments', { url: '/attach' });
```

I would like to tap into these state declarations whenever the state changes, and build a list of objects for displaying sub-navigation. Something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) { 
   // Get child states of 'toState' and build the UI
});
```

For example:

When the current state is 'home', display the following:

- Home
- Products

When the current state is 'products.details', display the following:

- Home
- Products

  - My Product
  - Images
  - Vendors
  - Attachments

...with the sub-navigation being built dynamically.

Is there a way of tapping into something like the `$stateProvider` and finding child states?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531871/angularjs-ui-router-get-list-of-child-states-of-a-given-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$state.get() returns a configuration object or array of all objects. You can then iterate through the returned array/object and make a tree structure.

The following function would return the states in your application in a tree format.

```
$scope.getStateTree = function() {
        var states = $state.get();
        var stateTree = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            var stateName = states[i].name;
            if (stateName != "") {
                if (stateName.indexOf(".") > -1) {
                    var children = stateName.split(".");
                    var currentTreeNode = stateTree[children[0]];
                    for (var j = 1; j < children.length; j++) {
                        if (!currentTreeNode.hasOwnProperty(children[j])) {
                            currentTreeNode[children[j]] = {};
                            currentTreeNode=currentTreeNode[children[j]];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!stateTree.hasOwnProperty(stateName)) {
                        stateTree[stateName] = {};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return stateTree;
    };
```