# angularjs ui-router: Get list of child states of a given state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Do you know a way in ui-router to get the list of child states of a given state?

I'm implementing a complex SPA with maybe 4 level deep navigation using ui-router.

I would like to implement a navigation tab interface for the second level generated automatically from the router table.

For that, I need to get the list of direct children of a given state (maybe is an abstract state). The only way that I've found to get the states is to do a `$state.get()` and obtain the full list of states, but that means that I'll have to parse child states on my own, and I think that's code already written in ui-router.

I let this question here in case there's anyone with experience in the source code or know of a plugin or module that can help me on this. Meanwhile I will do a research on my own and post results if I find something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, had to implement the functionality myself.

In the controller of the abstract route that has the tab interface, filtered the states using a regular expression taking advantage of the default naming convention for routes:

```
var routeName='Root.Parent'; // this is the "actual" route

// this regex is going to filter only direct childs of this route.
var secondRouteOnlyRegex = new RegExp(routeName + "\.[a-z]+$", "i");
var states = $state.get();

// this uses lodash to filter the states based on the regex
var navLinks = _.filter(states, (s) => {
    return secondRouteOnlyRegex.test(s.name) && !s.abstract;
});
$scope.tabs = navlinks;
```

My route definitions have a `data` property that contains the title and other metadata needed to render the tabs.

My template looks something like this (using bootstrap):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="state in tabs" ui-sref-active="active">
        <a href="{{state.url}}" ui-sref="{{state.name}}">{{state.data.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need something similar, so at least I know I have to implement it myself. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Couldnt you use [stateHelper](https://github.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper) and `$state.get()` to do this? Will check.

Answer (score 9):

I did this which is easier and faster:

```
var chillin = $state.get().filter(function(cState) { return cState.name.indexOf('parent.state.') === 0 });
```

Comment: +1, much nicer to use native array methods over underscore or lodash. 
However, you're not filtering out the parent route, thus not only grabbing children. To only grab child routes, add `if (cState.name === <parent-name>) return;`

Answer (score 2):

If you use [stateHelper](https://github.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper), it enables you to register states like this (from the *stateHelper* readme):

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.router', 'ui.router.stateHelper' ])
    .config(function(stateHelperProvider){
        stateHelperProvider
            .state({
                name: 'root',
                templateUrl: 'root.html',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'contacts',
                        template: '<ui-view />',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'list',
                                templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'products',
                        templateUrl: 'products.html',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'list',
                                templateUrl: 'products.list.html'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            })
            .state({
                name: 'rootSibling',
                templateUrl: 'rootSibling.html'
            });
      });
```

In your navigation controller you can then use the `children` attribute on the "root" state. For instance, I'm using this to display all children of the current state:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('TransportController', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.items = $state.current.children;     
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, this could be usefull in some cases, but in my particular case, I'm building my app from several modules, so each controller registrers to it's own module and so on. Then I read all the routes and create a navigation menu out of my modules and actions. The navigation menu directive doesn't have a clue of how the structure is, so it needs to be very generic.